# Azure build pipeline unable to download the dependences from azure artifact,

Tags: java, maven, build, azure-devops, azure-artifacts

I m trying to create build pipeline on azure devops server, my build pipeline is able to download dependences from Azure Artifact

````
2021-03-02T05:45:24.8329366Z [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
2021-03-02T05:45:24.8329608Z [INFO] Total time:  02:31 min
2021-03-02T05:45:24.8330187Z [INFO] Finished at: 2021-03-02T05:45:24Z
2021-03-02T05:45:24.8330469Z [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
2021-03-02T05:45:24.8330824Z [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project myapplication-commons-lib: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.myapplication.mdm.commons:myapplication-commons-lib:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at com.tibco.ebx.core:ebx-lib:jar:5.9.10: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.tibco.ebx.core:ebx-lib:jar:5.9.10: Could not transfer artifact com.tibco.ebx.core:ebx-lib:pom:5.9.10 from/to myapp-snapshots (https://myapplication.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/myapp-snapshots/maven/v1): Authentication failed for https://myapplication.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/myapp-snapshots/maven/v1/com/tibco/ebx/core/ebx-lib/5.9.10/ebx-lib-5.9.10.pom 401 Unauthorized -> [Help 1]
2021-03-02T05:45:24.8331113Z [ERROR] ```


YAML Pipeline
[![enter image description here][1]][1]


[![enter image description here][2]][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L34oP.png

YAML from pipeline 

- task: Maven@3
  displayName: 'Code Compilation'
  inputs:
    mavenPomFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/solution/core/build/maven/pom.xml'
    options: '-s $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/solution/core/build/maven/settings.xml'
    goals: package
    mavenAuthenticateFeed: true
````

Comment: You are not allowed (`m 401 Unauthorized -` to access the given repository)... https://myworld.pkgs.visualstudio.com ???

Comment: ohk what can be done to resolve this

Answer (score 0):

> ....401 Unauthorized

The 401 error is an authentication error.

Add the [Maven Authenticate task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/maven-authenticate?view=azure-devops) before calling Maven task. The Maven Authenticate task can provide credentials for Azure Artifacts feeds and external Maven repositories in the current user's settings.xml file.

[image]

If your azure artifacts are in the same Collection, you can directly select the corresponding feed in drop down list.

If yours is external azure artifacts(e.g. Azure Devops Service), you need to create a service connection(maven) in **Porject Settings -> Service Connections**.

[image]

**Update:**

If you couldn't use Maven Authenticate task, you could try the following steps to use the Settings.xml file.

Step1: Create a Setting.xml file.

You could navigate to **Azure Devops Service -> Artifacts -> Connect to feed -> Maven**.

[image]

Step2: In you Azure Devops Server, you could save your settings.xml to the path

```
%USERPROFILE%\.m2\settings.xml
```

You could refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/maven-authenticate?view=azure-devops#where-is-the-settingsxml-file-which-contains-the-authenticated-repositories-located).

On the other hand, when you add option to the Maven task.

For example:

```
- task: Maven@3
  displayName: 'Maven pom.xml'
  inputs:
   ...
    options: '-s filepath/settings.xml'
```

Comment: Step references task 'MavenAuthenticate' at version '0' which does not exist.
```- task: MavenAuthenticate@0
  displayName: 'Maven Authenticate'
  inputs:
    artifactsFeeds:```

Comment: If you couldn't use this task, you could try to manually create settings.xml file. Please refer to my update,

Comment: i added the details in setting.xml file

Comment: From the error message, You need to define a specific file path instead of use filepath/settings.xml . The filepath need to be specific .  If the settings.xml is exists in root directory of repo, you could use `$(build.sourcesdirectory)/ settings.xml`.

Comment: i have updated the question, i am changed the path, YAML has been updated in Question tab,

Comment: Do you mean that you still get the same error ?  Have you added the PAT in the Settings.xml file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229380/discussion-between-satyam-pandey-and-kevin-lu-msft).

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem recently in a Pipeline that has been working for quite a while.  In my case adding a NPM Authentication step in my pipeline did the trick:

```yaml
- task: npmAuthenticate@0
  inputs:
    workingFile: "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/path/to/my/.npmrc"
```